# Display image in hex from DB to browser

Tags: php, sql-server, image, hex

I have an image **(jpeg)** stored in my DB **(SQL Server)** and when I read it I got a hex code. But I can't display it to the browser, it doesn't understand and shows the pure code.

[Here's a hex code example](http://pastebin.com/ptp2C2B6)

I need help to achieve this. Thank you all in adv.

Comment: The hex dump you have... is that how it is stored in the database?  Is in, is there raw binary objects in the DB, or text with the hex of a binary file?

Comment: how is it stored in the database? BLOB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have PHP >= 5.4 you can use [hex2bin()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php).

If not you can use the alternative function posted on that page:-

```
/**
 * Converts the hex representation of data to binary
 *
 * http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php
 *
 * @param   string  $str        Hexadecimal representation of data
 *
 * @return  string              Returns the binary representation of the given data
 */
public function hex2bin($data)
{
    $bin    = "";
    $i      = 0;
    do {
        $bin    .= chr(hexdec($data{$i}.$data{($i + 1)}));
        $i      += 2;
    } while ($i < strlen($data));
    return $bin;
}
```

Then you just set your headers and echo the result out to the browser.

You'd be surprised what you can learn just by looking at the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/). Hopefully, this will work for you, or at least set you on the right track.